# How to use a variable as constructor property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, constructor, javascript-objects

```
function Volkswaggen($options) {

  $.each($options, function(k,v) {
    this.k = v;
  });
}
/* ============================== */

var $polo = new Volkswaggen({model: "Polo", doors: 3});

console.log($polo.model); // << I want this to return "Polo"
```

`$polo.model` returns undefined.

If I change `this.k = v;` to `this[k] = v;` and do `console.log(this.model)` *inside* the each loop, console returns "Polo undefined" and `console.log($polo);` also still returns undefined.

Any ideas?

[Code Screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfseY.png)

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/JCJWebDesign/zztqyvf4/1/

Comment: you have return nothing from a function . check https://jsfiddle.net/zztqyvf4/2/

Comment: Little note from germany: `Volkswaggen` should be spelled `Volkswagen` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Volkswaggen($options) {
    var self = this;
    $.each($options, function(k, v) {
        self[k] = v;
    });    
}

/* =========================================== */

var $polo = new Volkswaggen({model: "Polo", doors: 3});

console.log($polo.model);
```

inside `$.each`  `this`   is not the newly created object,jQuery says -"the keyword this refers to the element."

so what you should do is assign `this`  to another variable. lets say `self`  and use that instead. and you don't have to return anything
(self or this), JS  takes care of that

Working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3qcfd9mq/)

Comment: Thanks @Oxi!

I cannot believe I missed that.  What can I say? I'm not a morning person!

Answer (score 0):

You haved return nothing from function.

```js
function Volkswaggen($options) {     
  var temp = this;
  $.each($options, function(k, v) {       
    temp[k] = v;
  });
}

/* =========================================== */

var $polo = new Volkswaggen({model: "Polo", doors: 3});

console.log($polo.model);
alert($polo.model);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would that not be `return this;` otherwise it would be pointless to have a function that might process the options given

Comment: Inside $each, this does not point to the new object created. So even if you return this, there is no point. So assign this to self and add onto self. Please refer my answer for more

Comment: Yes inside `$.each` `this` points to its current element. So we need to change reference and then perform operation.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @ParthTrivedi :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically problem with assigning object property in current object. Here is correct code and it works.

```
 function Volkswaggen($options) {
   for (var k in $options) {
        if ($options.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
          this[k] = $options[k];
        }
      }    
    }

var $polo = new Volkswaggen({model: "Polo", doors: 3});
console.log($polo);
console.log($polo.model);
console.log($polo.doors);
```